# Trouble with combining threading and progressbar with a function

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, progress-bar

I have some code which asks the user to import a file and then it will be encrypted using a translator. When I try this the program hangs a lot with large files or any files in general. I've tried to solve this using threading and a progressbar but I've sort of hit a dead end - I don't know how to update the progressbar which will correspond with the amount of time it will take to encrypt the file. This is what I have so far:

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *
import threading

letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

encryption_code = 'LFWOAYUISVZMNXPBDCRJTQEGHK'

letters += letters.lower() 
encryption_code += encryption_code.lower()

enc = dict(zip(letters,encryption_code))

window = tkinter.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(window)
style.configure("BW.TLabel")

import_frame = tkinter.Frame(window)

def import_txt():
    global import_list    
    file_name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")]) 

    import_list = [] 

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        import_list = f.readlines()
        progressbar.pack()
        but1.pack()
        encrypttxt.pack()
    f.close() 

def encrypt_txt():
    global letters
    global encryption_code
    global import_list
    global translated
    progressbar.start()
    pre = "".join(import_list)
    translated = "".join([i.translate(str.maketrans(letters, encryption_code)) for i in import_list]) 
    display_txt.insert('insert', translated) 
    precrypt.insert('insert', pre)
    display_txt.pack(side=RIGHT)
    precrypt.pack(side=LEFT)

def end():
    if t.isAlive() == False:
        progressbar.stop()
        t.join()

toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(window)   
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(toplevel, orient = HORIZONTAL, mode = "determinate")
t = threading.Thread(target=encrypt_txt)
but1 = ttk.Button(window, text= "Stop", command=end)

display_txt = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(import_frame)
encrypttxt = ttk.Button(import_frame, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt_txt)
precrypt = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(import_frame)
start = ttk.Button(window, text="Start", command=import_txt)
start.pack()
import_frame.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you create thread but you don't start it. And you have to put you function inside that thread.

Comment: So how would I stop the loading bar when the file is encrypted. Currently, it does not stop once the file is finished encrypting. Updated my code.

Comment: use `progressbar.stop()` at the end of `encrypt_txt()`

Comment: Now the `progressbar` won't move.

Comment: learn how to use `threads` because you still don't start thread and your function is blocking `mainloop()` so `mainloop()` can't update progressbar.

Comment: use `command=lambda:t.start()` in place of `command=encrypt_txt`

Comment: Can you explain how `mainloop()` is being blocked?

Comment: `mainloop` is a loop which run (one-by-one) "get key and mouse events", "redraw element", "call function added by `after`", "run function when you press button", "run your functions". etc. If any element works too long then other elements can't be done.